# Issue with dir command in bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The program accomplishes to  find files on a remote server , I tried the following code to accomplish but the error i get is `network path not found` but if i  write just the `dir` command on the cmd it works fine.How can i solve this?

```
(for %%a in (host1) do ( 
   ;dir \\%%a\xxx\xx\xx\xx.xml /s ;
))>>op.txt
```

Comment: can you try `for %%a in (host1) do ( 
   dir \\%%a\xxx\xx\xx\xx.xml /s >>op.txt
)`?

Comment: no i still get the same error `network path not found`

Comment: what happens if you run `dir \\hostname\\xxx\xx\xx\xx.xml /s` alone

Comment: that works , maybe  i have to pass the server name in a different way instead of `%%a`

Comment: If you `echo` the `dir` command (ie insert the keyword `echo ` before the `dir`) does it show what you expect to execute?

Comment: yes it  displays

Comment: it is a computer name

Comment: i will modify it , if i echo `%%a` it displays host1 ,but why not i pass `%%a`  to a cmdlet , why isn't it working , i solved the problem using another scripting language , but i just want to know the reason why it doesn't work in this scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find files on a share of server **host1**, just use:

```
dir /s \\host1\share\xx.xml
```

There is no reason to employ **for**.

If the **host1** is a  text file with server names, one per line, use:

```
for /f %%a in (host1) do dir \\%%a\share\xx.xml
```

In either case you need to use the available share. Use `net view \\server` to learn share names.